# PX4 Multi-Vehicle Simulation with Gazebo : What is No ROS?

Tags: c++, simulation, ros, robot, px4

https://docs.px4.io/master/en/simulation/multi_vehicle_simulation_gazebo.html

What is the meaning of No ROS in that link and what is the difference between No ROS and simulation with ROS?

Comment: [ROS (Robot Operating System)](https://docs.px4.io/master/en/ros/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text at the very top of the page explains that they use different commands depending on whether you are using ROS or not.

> A different approach is used for simulation with and without ROS.

There is a separate section further down about how to do the same thing *with* ROS.